# XNA 4.0 Refresh AudioEngine, WaveBank and Others Not Found

Tags: xna, import

I'm going through the Learning XNA 4.0 book, and unfortunately I installed XNA 4.0 refresh. All the code up until now has worked, with the exception of me needing to remove the Framework.Net and Framework.Storage. (As a side question, will this be problematic later?)

The problem I'm having now is that in my Game1.cs file, I have imported all of the XNA.Framework libraries, and when I try and create instances of any of the following classes, an error pops up saying VisualStudio can't find them: AudiEngine, WaveBank, SoundBank, and Cue.

I have googled around for a while, and the only solution I saw was to import Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact, but this doesn't seem to exist for me.

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some googling (this is a verb now, and my spell check should know better) and I found the solution.

I'm more familiar with Java that C# so when everything online said to add a reference to the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact binary, I thought it was how you said 'import' in C#. For those of you who will inevitably make the same mistake as I have, you have to right click the reference folder in your project (NOT the one in the Content folder) and add a reference from there.

Hope this helps someone